# Entity Framework TPT inheritance edit a record in base class table and bind it to subclass table

Tags: entity-framework

I've used code first for linking to an existing database via TPT inheritance here in this code i have one base class called Person and 2 subclasses called Student and Teacher and both Student and Teacher class inherit from Person class

```
public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }
public class Student : Person
    {
        public int? Payment { get; set; }
    }


public class Teacher : Person
    {
        public int Wage { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my Context Class

```
public class PersonContext : DbContext
    {
        public PersonContext()
            : base("TPT")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<PersonContext>(null);
        }
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Persons");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().ToTable("Teachers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students");
        }
    }
```

I've inserted a record with FirstName and LastName and saved it in the `Persons` table, via adding a simple `Person` instance to the context. It's because I don't know the type of the person in that time. In another list, operator recognizes the record, and tries to add extra data to it (for example adding Payment for students). What should I do now? If I get that person's record and cast it to `Student` class and try to update it, I'll get this error:

> 'TablePerTypeInheritance.Models.Person' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Payment' and no extension method 'Payment' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'TablePerTypeInheritance.Models.Person' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I haven't used TPT before, can you clarify: What does your DbContext look like? 3 DbSets or just one?

Comment: cuz i want to add student or teacher not only a person i've created Dbset for each class

Answer (score 2):

You save a record of the type `Person`, so it will be always retrieved from the DB as `Person`.

In C# you can't cast a base class to a derived class. Such operation is invalid.

```
var person = new Person();
var student = (Student)Person; // doesn't compile
```

If you want to change the type of the record, you have to create a new object of the desired type.

```
var person = context.Persons.Find(1);
var student = new Student() {
    FirstName = person.FirstName,
    LastName = pesron.LastName
};

context.Persons.Remove(person);
context.Student.Add(student);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi my friend you have to use own sql command to do it.

```
var id = new SqlParameter("@id", std.StudentId);
var rate = new SqlParameter("@rate", std.Rate);
contex.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into ExcelentSudents values (@id,@rate)", id, rate);
```